# Length Of Curve $\gamma(t)=(t \cos t,t\sin t)$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the length of the curve $\gamma(t)=(t \cos t,t\sin t)$, $t\in[0,\pi]$

So I first start of saying that the curve is in $C^1$ and therefore I can use the $L(\gamma)=\int_a^b\|\gamma'(t)\|dt$

Is it right?

So

$\gamma'(t)=( \cos t-t \sin t,\sin t+t\cos t)$

$\|\gamma'(t)\|= \sqrt{(\cos t-t \sin t)^2+(\sin t+t\cos t)^2}=\\=\sqrt{\cos^2t -2t\cos t \sin t+t^2\sin ^2t+\sin ^2t+2t \cos t \sin t+t^2\cos ^2t}=\sqrt{1+t^2}$

So

$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{1+t^2}dt$

$t=\tan\theta, dt=\sec \theta d \theta$

$\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{1+\tan^2 t} \sec \theta d \theta=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sec^3 \theta d \theta=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sec \theta \cdot\sec^2\theta d\theta=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sec \theta \cdot(1+\tan^2\theta) d\theta$

$u=\tan \theta, du=\sec \theta d\theta$

$\int_{0}^{\pi}(1+u^2) du=u+\frac{u^3}{3}|_0^{\pi}=\tan\theta+\frac{\tan^3\theta}{3}|_0^{\pi}=\sqrt{1+t^2}+{(1+t^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}|_0^{\pi}=\\=\sqrt{1+\pi^2}+{(1+\pi^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}-2$

Which it wrong where is the mistake?

Comment: When you make the change of variables from $t$ to $tan(\theta )$, should the bounds of integration also change?

Comment: @gd1035 correct, but also the indefine integral does not come out right according to Wolfram

Comment: $\int \sqrt{1 + t^2}dt$ could be looked up in a table of integrals like here: http://integral-table.com/downloads/single-page-integral-table.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integral is $\frac{1}{2}[t\sqrt{1+t^2}+\ln(t+\sqrt{1+t^2})]_0^\pi=\frac{\pi\sqrt{1+\pi^2}+\ln(\pi+\sqrt{1+\pi^2})}{2}$. Your substitution $t=\tan\theta$ would also finish the problem (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed)), but the upper limit must become $\arctan\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

After the substitution $t=\tan \theta$ you must change the limits of integration and, more important, you have
$$
dt=\sec^2\theta d\theta
$$

(and the same for

$
u=\tan \theta \qquad du=\sec^2 \theta d \theta 
\quad$ 
that returns the integration to the starting point: $\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{1+u^2}du$

Comment: So I need to try different method then the $u$ substitution

Answer (score 1):

What about hyperbolic functions?:

$$t=\sinh x\implies dt=\cosh x\,dx\implies\int_0^\pi\sqrt{1+t^2}\,dt=\int_0^{\text{arcsinh}\pi}\sqrt{1+\sinh^2x}\cdot\cosh xdx=$$

$$=\int_0^{\text{arcsinh}\pi}\cosh^2x\,dx=\left.\frac12\left(x+\sinh x\cosh x\right)\right|_0^{\text{arcsinh}\pi}=\frac12\left(\text{arcsinh}\pi+\pi\sqrt{1+\pi^2}\right)$$